Getting SENDER_ID_MISMATCH, although I think I synchronized the service account and google.services.json files
I'm trying to convert from Legacy FCM messages to the V1 API. I'm using Elixir, so using the Pigeon OSS (v2) to provide the FCM interface, and have some improvements to that to use the Goth OSS to handle the OAUTH component.
I got the messaging set up with what I think I want the content to be, and am sending messages to Google, but I'm getting back 403 responses with SENDER_ID_MISMATCH in the ErrorCode and PERMISSION_DENIED in the status.
I'm using a service account file that I created with a firebase admin role, and I've tried a couple of others too. After seeing posts about the mismatch being between the app and the service account I checked and found that the app was using an incorrect google-services.json file, which I can't even find a record for. Interestingly, changing the file didn't affect the operation of the app against the old version of our software, so apparently it wasn't really in use. However changing the app to what, I think, matches the service account didn't help. I also had my test user (who knows how to build the Android app) log out of the updated app and back in, to make sure he got a new token, presumably created with the updated app/google-services.json. It's still not working.
The old services file showed an oauth_client, with an id and type. The new one doesn't have that. Do we need it? I think so, to make the Goth configuration work. We tried to figure out how to create it and there seems to be a lot of work, because apparently our apps (2) aren't in an organization, and to create one there seems to need the account owner (our CEO) to create a Cloud Identity and do a whole lot of other stuff that I can't even explain to him. Is that actually necessary? The old services file has the oauth_client ID and I don't think it was in an organization.
If you have any good ideas I'd love detailed steps to do this. I can create a new service account if needed, but what roles or other details do I need to add to it, and is there something I need to do to make sure it agrees with the google-services file?
The people who were the contacts for Google when the deprecation of the Legacy FCM API was announced didn't recognize the significance of the warning. I was trying to do something completely unrelated on June 17th which required accessed to our Google Cloud account, and I stopped to read emails, including the one warning us that we had three days left. So guess who got stuck fixing it???
I appreciate any detailed help you can give. Google's docs haven't been as helpful as I need.

It means that the project ID you're using is not the same project ID as the token you're sending to.

@Bob is there any meaningful way to debug that from the Google side? Something I can do to see what sender_id it's getting versus what choices it's expecting? I've tried working top down on this, so is there some way to work bottom up, from the mismatch back to the problem?

I have provided a very detailed information regarding migration to HTTP v1 API, please take a look. Hope this helps.

@Bob Let me say "Brilliant, thanks" first, then read and try to follow the instructions.

@Bob I'm still working through this incredibly painful and unenlightened process. I think your tips have helped a bit but I still haven't solved the mismatch.

Check step no 2 that is the reason for getting sender id mismatch

Step number 2 it is. The app was using a senderId from a different project that must have been created by the former developer. Once I switched that to a google-services file from the current firebase account I got things to match. Thanks @Bob

HTTP v1 was introduced in 2017. After many years of supporting both APIs, Firebase announced in June 2023 that the legacy API will be removed after one year.

Apps using the deprecated FCM legacy APIs for HTTP and XMPP should migrate to the HTTP v1 API at the earliest opportunity. Sending messages (including upstream messages) with those APIs was deprecated on June 20, 2023, and shutdown begins on July 22, 2024.

Old process of sending push won't work now and you need to change it completely.

They have removed Authorisation key and endpoint url got changed too. Now create New Private Key for server i.e (service-account-file.json) and use that key to generate bearer token.
Note : Don't get confused with client side json i.e google-services.json

Steps need to be followed :
1. Consider reading this post.

https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/migrate-v1

2. After that double check which step you are missing or doing wrong.

(403) PERMISSION_DENIED means you are Authenticated (your token is valid) , but you do not have Authorization to access the recourse in your URL.

This is due to conflict within your Firebase config when initializing the app.  You might be trying to use an old projectId/senderId, however your remaining configuration are still pointing to your new project in Firebase.

A sender ID: set in the code of your app. Android Studio uses automatically the Sender ID of your Firebase Project. If you are still using GCM, you have probably set manually the sender ID in the code of your app. The sender ID identifies your app to Firebase Cloud Messaging when it asks for a token.

More info - https://help.batch.com/en/articles/2901688-how-to-fix-a-mismatch-between-your-push-tokens-and-your-sender-id
3. Which Server to choose

Caution: Sending messages (including upstream messages) with the FCM XMPP and HTTP legacy APIs was deprecated on June 20, 2023, and will be removed in June 2024. If you are using the legacy FCM send APIs, we strongly recommend that you migrate to the HTTP v1 API or consider using the Admin SDK to build send requests.

https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/server#choosing-a-server-option
4. Server setup
https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/auth-server#node.js_2
Server side code :
URL url = new URL("https://www.googleapis.com/auth/firebase.messaging");
HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
httpURLConnection.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "Bearer " + getServiceAccountAccessToken());
httpURLConnection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json; UTF-8");
return httpURLConnection;

More information for token generation can be found here :
How do I create an Access Token from Service Account Credentials using REST API?
5. If you still facing issue consider reading this :

https://firebase.google.com/support/faq

They have covered almost all type of question you may have.

I was getting SENDER_ID_MISMATCH because the app was using a senderId from a former developer, not from the current owner account. I'm not even sure how that was working with Legacy, but I also don't care now.

@Sinc glad my answer helped you
